# Laravel 5.1 migration new table not working

Tags: laravel-5.1, laravel-migrations

I have got some problem with migration.
I create new migrate file

```
php artisan make:migration create_menu_table --create=menu
```

then i edit the new Migration file
and when i try migrate it's not working

I tried:

```
php artisan migrate
php artisan migrate --force
php artisan migrate:refresh
php artisan migrate:refresh --seed
php artisan migrate:rollback
php artisan migrate:reset
```

but they do not add created table

I do not have any errors

Thanks for help

Comment: None of the artisan commands give you any errors? Do they give you any successful messages?

Comment: Did you choose your correct DB driver?

Comment: I do not have any errors. When i use `php artisan migrate:reset` they create only older tables

Comment: So when you run `migrate` command, it creates only old tables? Are you sure it creates them, or they already exist so nothing actually happen. Would you please provide the command output after running it?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure because they clear all table... `php artisan migrate:refresh
Rolled back: 2015_11_29_071555_create_articles_category_table
Rolled back: 2015_11_27_100057_create_role_user_table
Rolled back: 2015_11_27_100026_create_permission_role_table
Rolled back: 2015_11_27_095944_create_permissions_table
Rolled back: 2015_11_27_095845_create_roles_table
Rolled back: 2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table
Rolled back: 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table`

when i use
`php artisan migrate`
nothing happens

Comment: is it fresh laravel install or moving from one server to nexrt?

Comment: Fresh install, i added some tools i.e: mcamara laravel-localization, bestmono filemanager, I created few models and controllers and that is all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `composer dumpautoload` and then try `php artisan migrate:refresh` again.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The only other thing I can suggest if manually deleting your tables in your db and then running `php artisan migrate`. Also check that all of your migrations have a table name in their `up()` method i.e. `Schema::create('table-name',...'`.

Comment: I just did it, and i had some problem with one table, i tried add index to text field... Now it works :) Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

add schema ::defaultStringLength(191) to migrate file(put in every file migrate)

like this

```
public function up()
    {
        schema::defaultStringLength(191);
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string ('Name');
            $table->float('price');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```